# Rendering after dispatch in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I have one doubt with react-redux. 
The component must be rendered after finish fetching data. The current code returns always `{}`. How can I solve this issue?

```
function Category(props) {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  props.dispatch(categoryActions.fetch());
  useEffect( () => {
    setCategories(props.categories)
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <Container className={classes.root}>
        .....
    </Container>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    categories: state.categories,
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      dispatch,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have some questions:

1. What does `const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);` do?
   `categories` are provided as props to `Category` component by `Connect`.
   `useState` hook is used to define and control internal state.
   It's not conflicting technically since you can call them `props.categories` and  `categories` respectively but there might be confusion.
2. What actions do you want to dispatch in the component?
   `mapDispatchToProps` looks doing nothing.
   Have a look at their [official example](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-jwt-authentication-example

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to my article.
This is my categoryActions.

Comment: Can I have a look at `CategoryActions.fetch()`?

Comment: [link] https://gist.github.com/huangxiaoxuan0621/c35ea2e3dc0f3d3c10e50f241ee50e0d

Comment: How are you importing `CategoryActions`?

Comment: This is a component to be imported. [link]https://gist.github.com/huangxiaoxuan0621/2e05118c2823c82f251b539e0cc63336

Comment: You said the current code always return `{}`, return value from what, please?